# How to parse the number 4 using optical character recognition

Tags: java, algorithm, screen-scraping, ocr

I'm working on an OCR algorithm which is given an image containing some numbers. I want it to simply detect each image, and separate it from the others.

It is working great for all numbers from 0-9 except for the number 4, which is giving me a lot of trouble.

Here is my source image:

[image: source image]

Here is the result of a few of the numbers from parsing it:

[image: 0] [image: 1] [image: 2] [image: 2] [image: 5] [image: 6] [image: 7] [image: 8] [image: 9] [image: .]

As you can see, they're all being parsed perfectly. The only thing which is giving me a world of trouble, is 4. Here is how the number 4 looks:

[image: 4]

The problem I'm having is with detecting the left-most corner of 4, in order to include the whole digit. 
Here is how my algorithm is traversing down when it tries to detect the left boundary of each character (the blue dots indicate the path taken by the algorithm):

[image: path taken by algorithm]

If you open the image in another tab and zoom in, you might be able to see better what its doing.

As you can see, it moves down and to the left until it encounters the background twice. When it does, it takes that to mean that the image's left-most boundary has been reached. It works fine for all other images, except for 4, where you can see that it encounters the background twice and stops, but if it instead continued downwards by two more pixels, then it would encounter more of 4 and would find its real left-most edge.

I'm not sure how to do this in a way that won't break it for the other numbers. Here's my actual code in case it helps:

```
    int misses = 0;
    int maxMisses = 2;
    while (y < image.getHeight() && x >= 0 )
    {
        markPixel(x, y);
        color = image.getRGB(x, y);
        if (! reader.isForeground(color))
            misses++;

        if (misses < maxMisses)
        {
            y++;
            x--;
            continue;
        }
        x++;
        break;
    }        
    if (x < 0)
        x = 0;
    return x;
```

**Edit:** I have been able to achieve some improvement by just traversing all the way down the image rather than stopping on encountering 2 background pixels, storing the x coordinate each step when i encounter the foreground pixel, then sorting the matches in ascending order and returning their lowest result. It works somewhat better. New 4 image:

[image: new 4]

Its not yet perfect. Also, the 9 looks a bit smaller:

[image: new 9]

New path traversed by algorithm:

[image: new path]

Updated code:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    int yB = y;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        y = yB;
        while (y < image.getHeight() && x >= 0 )
        {
            markPixel(x, y);
            color = image.getRGB(x, y);
            if ( reader.isForeground(color))
                matches.add(x);

            y++;                
        }      
        x--;
    }

    Collections.sort(matches);
    return matches.get(0);
```

Anyone got any ideas for getting the last imperfection out of 4?

Comment: As I can see from the source image you posted, a different approach would be to identify the "blank" space between digits; and then trim each segmented digit to get the "minimum" digit rectangle. Blank spaces are those "pixels columns" not containing any foreground pixel. Would this approach work for your case?

Comment: you could move back a few pixels if you see the left most edge has foreground pixels

Comment: @ratchetfreak wouldn't that just cause it to continue right till it finds the right-most corner of the image rather than the left as he needs?

Comment: You could also change the condition to check if the pixel down **or** left is a hit. It's only a miss if neither are foreground. Moving left **and** down ensures you can't find anything with an angle over 45 degrees. If you change fonts, that could be a bigger problem.

Comment: @Geobits Ding ding.. that seems to be the right answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from my comment, this seems like the way to do it with minimal modifcation from your posted algorithm:

Instead of moving both down and left when checking the next pixel, check them independently. It's only a miss if both the lefter(?) and lower pixels are a miss. This will help with any angles that are over a 45 degree slope, which you may encounter if you change fonts, etc.

---

**However,**

If you're willing to change your algorithm, I think other answers may be more robust in the end.

- **From Durandal's answer:** Walk around the digit in a circle, tracking the min x/y and max x/y. To get the lower left corner, it's `min x, max y`, assuming the origin is upper left. The only problem I see you running into here are islands(`i`, `j`) or extremely italicized fonts were the characters may overlap in the x direction.
- **From user2399923's comments:** Finding empty columns to divide characters works well, too. It wouldn't be affected by islands, but would be by the extreme italics case mentioned above, since there may not *be* empty columns in that case.
- **From blgt's answer:** The flood-fill method is also good, and rather the standard, I think. It needs adaptation for islands, but wouldn't be affected by italics, unless the characters were actually touching. It doesn't matter if there are "holes" in the numbers(eg `8`) because you're only interested in the min/max x/y values of the flooded region. By definition, none of those points would be a hole.

Comment: Your answer works perfectly, except check this image (zoom in a lot): http://i.imgur.com/4QwhmbS.png . You'll see that where it stops on 4, there actually is a gap both on the left and at the bottom.. any ideas?

Comment: Ah, the trace is actually *outside* the image. I thought you were tracing on the foreground edge. In that case, change it to check the pixel on the right of the trace spot. In your specific case, the next step on the 4 would be straight down, since a foreground pixel exists on the right but not below.

Comment: That's much better, but just a bit of 4 is still being left.. http://i.imgur.com/q9RDdKJ.png

Comment: You shouldn't be moving both down and left in that last step. If there's no foreground down, just move straight down. If you move at a 45 degree angle every time, it'll never work.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. One question, if I tried a fill algorithm on the same image, do you think it will be done in the same, less, or more time as what i'm using here? I need to parse them asap.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. I'd *think* that this would be quicker than fill, simply because you're checking less pixels. The only sure-fire way to know is to run both a bunch and benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just walk clockwise along the image contour, until you get all the way back (or sufficiently near) to the position where you encountered your first black dot?

A simple min/max tracking variable pair would give the digit images rectangle naturally while you traverse the path. Also this would work independently of the typeface used, as long as the characters do not consist of multiple islands (think of the letter i) and do not overlap/connect to each other.

Edit: The TC mentioned flood filling the glyph. I think thats an excellent idea, even better than my above approach.

Just find the first black pixel, then run a flood fill with that pixel as the starting point - if implemented to *copy* pixels into a separate image each pixel it selects to fill it would even work out if the typeface kerning makes adajacent glyphs have overlapping bounding rectangles (This may need two passes to implement, first to find the bounding rectangle, second to actually copy the pixels).

Comment: I encounter the first pixel in the lower left corner of the image.. (for numbers like 1 and 7 it could be in the center of the image). How would reading clockwise help me find the lower left corner of the number..?

Comment: You track the min/max x value encountered along the way, so you can easily see where the far left/right side of the image is.

Comment: So you're essentially saying draw a circle around the number and record the x values it encounters where the foreground color is found? But I can see it missing 4, i.e it could draw a circle around it but not encounter the lower left corner of 4

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in "min/max" that may made it a little confusing. I wouldn't call it drawing a circle, but in essence thats exactly it. You follow the outline of the glyph and track min(x) and max(x) (possibly y, too) while following the outline. Its a little more complicated than your initial approach, but not as easily fooled as well. The "flood fill" approach you mentioned in the comments works out the same, based on the black pixels instead of the white ones. It may even be a little simpler to implement (flood fill is a well known problem, so there are probably examples available)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way of doing what you describe is flood filling the image. Works for separating any non-disjoint characters (ie. doesn't work out-of-the-box for "i", "j", etc., but it's not too hard to adapt to that)

What you describe sounds rather more involved. You don't need to reinvent the wheel when there's already solutions for that.

Link -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: I've considered that, but for numbers like 4, 5, 8, etc which contain gaps within the numbers themselves, it doesn't seem like it would work. Or will it?

Comment: It will, it just needs a bit of additional logic for px islands

Comment: Can you clarify what sort of logic? I'm not talking about characters like i , I only have to parse digits from 0.9

Comment: I'd like to try this method but I don't know where to start, can you help me out?

Comment: I.e, can I use flood fill to get the width, starting x, an ending x position for a character?